# Firebase cloud functions "Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred."

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I made a 2º gen function on cloud functions.

```js
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('canplace', (req, res) => {
    print("hi mark");
});
```

When i try call it.

```cs
functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;

functions.GetHttpsCallable("canplace").CallAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully) {
      Debug.Log("finished");
      Debug.Log(task.Result.Data);
  }else if (task.IsFaulted) {
      Debug.Log("Error: " + task.Exception.Message);
  }else if (task.IsCanceled) {
      Debug.Log("Canceled ");              
  }            
});
```

I get that error:

```
Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (INTERNAL) ---> Firebase.Functions.FunctionsException: INTERNAL
  at Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableReference.<CallAsync>b__9_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/functions/src/HttpsCallableReference.cs:88 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Functions.FunctionsException: INTERNAL
  at Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableReference.<CallAsync>b__9_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/functions/src/HttpsCallableReference.cs:88 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 <---

UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
FirebaseManager/<>c:<InitializeFirebase>b__15_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableResult>) (at Assets/Scripts/FirebaseManager.cs:56)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
```

I tryed debug the code both on unity and on firebase but still no sucess, i also tryed look videos and similar problems but didnt find any answer, not even on the API.